# Bluetooth can no longer discover devices. 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, usb, bluetooth

Bluetooth used to work, but for some reason it disconnects from the headphones about 5 minutes after connecting. I googled online, tried a ton of stuff, purged/re-installed a ton of stuff, and now Bluetooth can't even find my headphones anymore.

```
➜ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:0c1a Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b59a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

➜ bluetoothd -d -n
bluetoothd[5422]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
bluetoothd[5422]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing main.conf
bluetoothd[5422]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DiscoverableTimeout' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[5422]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'PairableTimeout' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[5422]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'AutoConnectTimeout' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[5422]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'Name' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[5422]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'Class' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[5422]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DeviceID' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[5422]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'ReverseServiceDiscovery' in group 'General'
D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.235" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file
bluetoothd[5422]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i basically purged every package that had to do with bluetooth, reinstalled them, rebooted. I could now connect to my headphones, but it still disconnects from my headphones after 5mins.

So more googling revealed that tlp was the culprit, so i followed the steps in [this article](https://serenity-networks.com/bluetooth-mouse-disconnects-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-intel-7260)

Basically add my bluetooth adapter to tlp's `USB_BLACKLIST`

`sudo nano /etc/default/tlp`

```
...
USB_BLACKLIST=”<Your usb adapter ID gotten from lsusb>”
...
```

Comment: Why don't you accept your own answer?

Comment: I'll be able to do that in 10hours

Comment: It's in the [FAQ](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#btusb) too.